# AttributeError: module 'pathlib' has no attribute '_Accessor'

Tags: python, artifactory, accessor, pathlib

When i use python 3.9, everything is OK

but when i use python 3.11, show error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  
File "C:\project\test\tools\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
  
File "C:\Users\ba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\artifactory.py", line 406, in <module>
    class _ArtifactoryAccessor(pathlib._Accessor):
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pathlib' has no attribute '_Accessor'
```

python code like this:

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
```

python version:

```
Python version is 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

artifactory version:

```
Name: artifactory

Version: 0.1.17

Summary: A Python to Artifactory interface
```

how to fix this issue?

I wonder to know how to fix this problem or anyother lib to replace

Comment: Remove the python artifactory module and use this one: https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory

Comment: Pathlib removed accessors in 3.11, see this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue43012

Comment: thanks this answer has fix my problem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error message you're seeing, "AttributeError: module 'pathlib' has no attribute '_Accessor'," indicates that you are trying to access an attribute or method called `_Accessor` in the `pathlib` module, but Python cannot find it because it doesn't exist.

The `pathlib` module in Python is used for working with file paths and directories, and it doesn't have an attribute called `_Accessor`. If you are encountering this error, it is likely due to a mistake in your code.

Here are some common reasons why you might encounter this error and how to resolve them:

1. Typo: Check your code for any typos in the attribute name. Make sure you are using the correct attribute or method name.
2. Incorrect Usage: Verify that you are using the `pathlib` module correctly. Make sure you have imported it correctly and are using its classes and methods in the intended way.
3. Compatibility: In rare cases, this error could be caused by compatibility issues between Python versions or packages. Ensure that your Python installation is up-to-date and that you are using compatible versions of any third-party packages that use `pathlib`.

Without seeing your specific code, it's challenging to provide a more detailed solution. If you can provide more context or code snippets, I would be happy to help you further troubleshoot the issue.